# Java merge two cells into one in EXCEL

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to merge two cells into one

```
 for (String cellLLL : sheetNumd) {
                XSSFSheet sheets = workbook.getSheet(cellLLL);
                
                if (sheets != null) {

                    for (int rowNum = 4; rowNum < sheets.getLastRowNum() + 1; rowNum++) {

                            Row row = sheets.getRow(rowNum);

                            //sheets.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(4, 5, 6, 6));

                            if (row != null) {
                                for (Cell cell : row) {
                                    int columnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();


                                    switch (columnIndex) {
                                        case 6:
                                            cellValue6 = cell.getStringCellValue();
                                            break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (cellLLL.equals("Sheet1")) {
                            list6.add(cellValue6);
                        }
```

The cells I want to merge are G5 and G6

In my example I comment out the code where I am trying to do it. But if I run it, then I get an error -

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add merged region G5:G6 to sheet because it overlaps with an existing merged region (G5:G6).
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Please tell me

The library I am using is Apache Poi

Comment: The message of the `IllegalStateException` is pretty clear, isn't it? Why is the code line `sheets.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(4, 5, 6, 6));` inside a loop? It always merges only `G5:G6`, so why calling this multiple times inside a loop? The error gets thrown when it gets called the second time because then `G5:G6` are merged already and cannot be merged again.

Comment: @Axel Richter I tried to take out this line of code for a loop. But nothing happens